# How to set a formula containing a structured reference in a cell using vba

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I am having issues setting this formula to a cell.
It is the first time I am trying to set a formula containing a structured reference to a cell using VBA and I am probably missing something obvious..
But until now my internet research didn't help me and I couldn't find the solution myself, despite trying.
I hope someone here can help.

```
Sheets("To Do List").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=IF([@Deadline]<=(TODAY()+30);""Yes"";""No"")"
```

Comment: One issue is `[@Deadline]` What is this value? Is it a variable in your VBA?  Or how would you reference it in your spreadsheet? Another issue is the semicolons in your IF formula. Excel uses commas to separate the parameters.

Comment: All formulas using VBA needs to be in American English format.  Change the `;` to `,`.

Comment: The [@Deadline] must be a table entry, right? The only issue I see is the semi-colon.

Comment: Although I'm also a bit confused about the first bit, is that not supposed to fill a range? does it not just fill the last row?

Comment: Thank you guys!
I completely overlooked the semicolon...
FYI, yes [@Deadline] is a table entry and the formula I wrote is to fill in just 1 cell in the table.
Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the semicolon, which should have been a comma.
Simple, but easily overlooked..
Thank you for the help guys!